# Java List.iterator() not returning wrong parametized iterator

Tags: java, generics

I have a `List<List<String>>` and I would expect the `iterator()` method to  return an `Iterator<List<List<String>>`, but what I get is an `Iterator<List<String>>`.

I cannot figure out what is going on???

I am using JDK 1.7.

Comment: Why do you expect an `Iterator<List<List<String>>`? Don't you expect to iterate over the elements?

Comment: Nothing but being tired apparently! This was totally my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a List of `List<String>`(List of Lists of Strings) so when you're iterating over it your iterator will return a `List<String>`(List of String) on each call to `iterator.next()`. That's why its type is `Iterator<List<String>>`, it iterates over lists of strings.

Comment: Oh wow... It is apparently too early in the morning for me to be programming. I was pulling the `List<List<String>>` from a map, cycling through the keyset, and then iterating over each one. This was a case of tunnel vision thinking I should have the `Map` loop, then a `List<List<String>>` loop and then a `List<String>` Loop. Time for a break I think!